# How do I search multiple tables in an MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, join

I have 2 tables (`Topics` and `Comments`) in an MVC application.  I would like to query the `comments` table, but also return the `title` from the `topic` table.

I believe I'm using EF.  I would use SQL, but I'm not sure if that is possible for an MVC application.

Using SQL I would do the following:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Comment, t.Title 
FROM Comments c INNER JOIN Topics t
ON c.TopicId = t.Id
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"I believe I'm using EF"_ **?!?!?!?!**

Comment: I know what `EF` is, I don't know how can someone "believe" what ORM he is using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your sql query is written using LINQ:

```
var query = _db.Comments.Join(
    _db.Topics,
    c => c.TopicId,
    t => t.Id,
    (comment, topic) =>
       new
       {
           Comment = comment,
           Topic = topic
       });
```

Comment: Thank you.  Does the (comment, topic) part represent a cast of some sort?  I have not seen anything other than single characters before the => characters.

Comment: @alockrem, It doesn't cast anything, thinnk of it like an alias for the first joined entity `Comments` and the other for the second joined entity `Topics` so that you can select accross the tow tables (entities)

Answer (score 0):

It is easily possible, use LINQ and EF. It would look something like this:

```
Dim Comments = Comments.
    Where(function(x) x.Topic.Id = ???).
    Select(function(x) New with {
        .Comment = x.Comment,
        .Title = x.Topic.Title
    })
```

That returns an `IQueryable(Of Anonymous Type)`

Then for each entry, you can just use the properties like any other...
    Dim A = Item.Comment
    Dim B = Item.Title